# Setting a TreeViewItems ItemTemplate dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a TreeView which i build up in code recursively. I would like to change the template of each TreeViewItem so that i can add in images etc. into the header. I have tried setting the ItemTemplate of the TreeView Item by creating a static resource within the XAML

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemControlTemplate">
      <sdk:TreeViewItem Background="Purple" >
        <TextBlock Text="Foo"></TextBlock>
      </sdk:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and then use it for each node created in code like so

```
myNode.ItemTemplate = DirectCast(Me.Resources("TreeViewItemControlTemplate"), DataTemplate)
```

I would assume this would then change the look of the items (in this example, just create a load of empty TreeViewItems with purple backgrounds). Instead, the TreeView just ignores these templates, and draws it as normal.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that I need to set the HeaderTemplate instead of the ItemTemplate.